# SQL relationship for tagging people in photos

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a document imaging application in C# with SQL Server to catalog ancestor photos. In one table are all the ancestors and in another I am storing the photos along with information about the photo. Obviously, each ancestor can have one or more photos. This design is easy, I've setup a one to many relationship and it works great.

Here is the issue: how do I handle a photo that has multiple people in it? This seems like a many to one relationship except that the many would also be many.

Comment: Can you use a [many-to-many relationship?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!  BJ, thanks for editing my initial post and not just deleting it.  Much better.
oerkelens, thanks for the celerity.

I created the extra table with three fields: keyPersonID, keyLineNo and fldPhotoID.  The keyLineNo provides the one-to-many along with the foreign key field for the person and a way to sort the results.  I then used fldPhotoID for the one-to-one for my photos.

Once I saw your response it all made sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a many-to-many relationship. This is actually quite common.

It is usually solved with the help of an extra table.

So if you have Person and Photo, you create an extra table PersonPhoto.

This table contains (at least) two fields, PersonId and PhotoId.

No you define a one-to-many relationship from Person to PersonPhoto basied on PersonId and another one-to-many from Photo to PersonPhoto, based on PhotoId.

Efectively you now have a many-to-many relationship between Person and Photo: any photo can contain many people, and any person can be in many photos.

Comment: Thank You!  I started thinking about this but could not find anything so I doubted myself.  So my hang up IS do I need two fields or three?  In a 'typical' one-to-many you have a foreign key based off one keyed field in the primary (the one) and the same value in the secondary (the many) along with an additional field.  In a PO system you would have a PO # tied to a PO # and Line number.  Would the Person ID to Person ID plus photo ID work or, if I have multiple photos for one person, would I need an additional field (line number)?